# Get a number in an interval

Tags: java, math

I would like to get a number between 5 and 250 from two variables according to the following pseudo-code:

```
arg[1-19] * something = [5 - 250]
```

`arg` will contain values (whole numbers) in the interval `[1 - 19]`; `something` could be any whole number.

The problem is that I obtain the same result using different combinations of `arg` and `something`:

```
arg: 1, something: 10 => result 10
arg: 2, something:  5 => result 10
```

How can I make sure that the result is different for any different pair of `arg` and `something`?

Is there a mathematical function or a function in java to do this?

Comment: It may help to see a code snippet.

Comment: You're question is really unclear. You're result is correct cause you're doing `1*10` or `2*5` which will result in 10. So where is your problem ?

Comment: I can't even figure out what your inputs are, and what your desired output is. Write the signature of the method you want to implement. Write the javadoc of this method.

Comment: Your 'something' can be `(int)((new Random().nextInt(251) + 5) / arg)` where arg is any argument (in the range 1 - 19)

Comment: @JedaiCoder Please don't laugh at me (I have no clue about Java, and I don't know what `nextInt()` does), but there seems to be something wrong with your code. Suppose that `arg = 1`, then your code theoretically could give 255, right?

Comment: I am voting for re-opening that question. IMHO, it is quite clear what he is asking: Is there a method to get a number between 5 and 250 by multiplication of two other numbers, when one of the other number is between 1 and 19, so that each different pair of the other numbers will yield a different result?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have a problem with programming. Instead, I think you should go one step back and try to understand your problem at mathematical level. Consider the equation

```
(1) a * b = C
```

for any (arbitrarily chosen) C, with `a`, `b` and `C` being whole numbers.

*Unless* `a` and `b` are *both* prime, there will at least be one pair of other `a, b` which also satisfy the equation. The proof is very simple if you think about it for a minute:

Suppose that `a` is not prime (the proof would be the same for `b` being not prime). Then there must be at least two whole numbers `p` and `a'` (`p` not being one by definition) so that

```
(2) a = p * a'
```

Now define that

```
(3) b' = p * b
```

Using equations (2) and (3), you can re-arrange equation (1) like that:

```
(4) C = a * b = (p * a') * b = a' * (p * b) = a' * b'

q.e.d
```

Here, since `p != 1` (by definition - see above), `a != a'` and `b != b'`.

This means that you must have both factors `a, b` prime if you want to guarantee that every different pair `(a, b)` will give a different result `a * b`.

You did not tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, but probably there is a better solution than multiplying two whole numbers.

For example, if we knew that your `something` is always less than ten (i.e. is `0, 1, ..., 9`), you could do `(arg * 10) + something` (this is only an example to show the principle; it would give values between `10` and `199` considering the restriction for `arg` you have mentioned, so it is actually not a solution to your problem; I have chosen that numbers because our decimal system basically works that way :-) and thus you already know about it).

And finally, so trivial that it possibly doesn't come to mind, remember that `a * b = b * a` (multiplication is commutative at least for our whole, real and irrational numbers and some more which I don't dare to mention). Applied to your problem: `arg * something = something * arg`. Of course, this is still true even if `arg` and `something` are both prime. It is inevitable that you get the same result if you exchange the values of `arg` and `something`. This might or might not be acceptable for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If `something` can take more than `12` values, this is not possible, as your input space will have a size of at least `19 * 13 = 247` whereas your output space has a size of `245`.

If `something` takes less than `12` values, you can simply do: `19 *$something + arg + 4` assuming you map the values of `something` to the interval `[0,n]`

Comment: Upvoted for the input space size consideration ...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to given an "arg" number you return a "something" number such that the result of `arg*something` is insiade a given interval, try this :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(findNumber(2, 5, 250));
    }

public static int findNumber(int arg, int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randMin;
    int randMax;
    if(min%arg == 0){
        randMin = min/arg;
    } else {
        randMin = (min / arg) + 1;
    }
    randMax = max/arg;
    int result = rand.nextInt(randMax+1-randMin);
    result = result + randMin;
    return result;
}
```